# Что означают данные строки в коде?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/stack:200000000")
#pragma GCC optimize("Ofast")
#pragma GCC target("sse,sse2,sse3,ssse3,sse4,popcnt,abm,mmx,avx,tune=native")
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
```

Что ознают данные строки в коде ?

Comment: Означают они настройки компиляции и линковки

Comment: это на что-то влияет ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Расширения компиляторов

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/stack:200000000")
```

Команда линковщику сделать стек побольше

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
```

Не выводить в Visual C++ предупреждения о небезопасных функциях

```
#pragma GCC optimize("Ofast")
#pragma GCC target("sse,sse2,sse3,ssse3,sse4,popcnt,abm,mmx,avx,tune=native")
```

Настройки для компилятора GCC - как я понимаю, первая строка - настройки оптимизатора (точнее не скажу), вторая - указание целевой архитектуры, для которой компилировать программу.

В любом случае, такие нестандартные расширения описаны в документации к конкретному компилятору.

Comment: они могут ускорить работу программы,я верно понял ?

Comment: я это вижу  у некоторых спортивных программистов ,поэтому и интересуюсь

Comment: Ускорить - ну, при очень точно подобранной оптимизации. Первые два из моего ответа - что для Visual C++ - нет, к скорости отношения не имеют. Разве что кто-то хочет часто выделять большой массив в стеке, а не в динамической памяти - ну тогда разве что... Но все то же самое достигается ключами командной строки.

Comment: спасибо большое за ответ :)